# How to read the device ID of an AARDVARK adapter?

Tags: i2c, embedded, digital-communications, usb-device

I am using a [Total Phase AARDVARK adapter](https://www.totalphase.com/products/aardvark-i2cspi/) as an I2C host. Each AARDVARK has a unique ID (or S/N) that's used for communication with the software. That ID is printed on a sticker on the device. Is there a programmatic way to read the device ID?

I can't find a reference to this in the manual or elsewhere.

Comment: That's not an electrical engineering question. That's how to use an electrical device question, or how to write software for it. The software API likely has a function for that. Have you read the manual or API refence?

Comment: @Justme - could you suggest a better site to post this?  "I cannot find a reference to this in the manual or elsewhere"

Comment: How to get the ID is explained in the Aardvark API documentation. Have you read it?

Comment: Some of it. But mostly the AARDVARK documentation. Didn't see that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, might help someone.

Following the short discussion in the comments to the question, I downloaded the [AARDVARK API](https://www.totalphase.com/products/aardvark-software-api/?___) package, extracted it and started writing a Python script for reading the ID. Then I noticed the package includes a program named `aainfo.exe` which when executed prints the list of connected devices, including their IDs:

```
Total Phase Aardvark(tm) Host Adapter Information Utility
(c) 2002-2008 Total Phase, Inc.  All rights reserved.

Detecting Aardvark devices...
2 devices found.

Available devices:
  Port (  0) - [ firmware v3.51 / hardware v3.00 / serial 2239-060480 ]
  Port (  1) - [ firmware v3.51 / hardware v3.00 / serial 2239-066876 ]

... press enter to exit ...
```